# There exists a isomorphism $f$ such that for every $k \in K \,$, $f(k) k^{-1} \in H$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G=H \times K$ and $G=H \times L$ be two decomposition of group $G$ into its normal subgroups. Prove that there exists a isomorphism $f: K \longrightarrow L$ such that for every $k \in K$, we have $f(k) k^{-1} \in H$.

Note: In the situation described in the question, we know that $K \cong L$ and $G/H \cong K$.

Comment: What exactly is $f$ supposed to do? With what information we have, we could just let $f$ be the identity on $G$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that for any $k\in K$, we have $(1,k)\in H\times K$, and this can be written uniquely as $(h,l)\in H\times L$. Now we map $k$ to $l$. This is a homomorphism since $(1,k_1k_2)=(1,k_1)(1,k_2)=(h_1,l_1)(h_2,l_2)$ so $k_1k_2$ maps to $l_1l_2$. Then it is injective since if $x \mapsto 1_L$ then $x=(h,1_L)$, so $x\in H$, which implies that $x=(h,1_K)\in K$ so the kernel is trivial. It is onto since if $l\in L$ and $l=h^{-1}k$ for some $h\in H$, $k\in K$, then $k=hl$ which implies $k\mapsto l$ as desired. Note that $f(k)=l$ such that $l=hk$ for some $h$, so $f(k)k^{-1}=h\in H$.

Answer (score 0):

Every element $k$ of $K$ can be written as $k=hl$ for unique $h\in H$, $l\in L$, define $\phi:K\to L$ as $\phi(k)=l$ where $l$ satisfy the relation above, in this case

$$\phi(k)k^{-1}=lk^{-1}=h^{-1}\in H\ \ .$$

Isn't $\phi$ an isomorphism?.